# what is the meaning of "," in R?

Tags: r

I am new to R. Please forgive me if you think this question is too simple. I saw one example like this lately.

```
x <- factor ( c( "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no" ) )
attr (, "levels")
```

I understand attr in R is used to find the attributes of an object. What does "," mean here ?

Comment: `attr(,"levels")` means that you left the first argument in `attr` blank.  It would likely result in an error. Also, `attributes` should be used to view attributes, `attr` to set them.

Comment: Actually, the getting and setting is more of a personal preference.  It's the first sentence that's important.

Comment: Thanks very much for all your comments. I was taking R course from coursera ( with due respect, and I like that course ). That is one example there. I just tried it in R console and it did give an error. In the very beginning, I thought it is because the we only have one object x. So, if it is omitted, it is x by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `attr(,"levels")`, it means that you left the first argument in `attr` blank.  This results in an error since the function cannot be used with an empty first argument (Well, actually it can. See below).

```
> x <- factor ( c( "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no" ) )
> x
# [1] yes yes no  yes no 
# Levels: no yes
> attr(, "levels")
# Error in attr(, "levels") : argument 1 is empty
```

You can get a meaningless result with

```
> attr(which = "levels", exact = FALSE)
# NULL
```

but that makes no sense because we haven't passed an object to `attr` to get the attribute.

For a meaningful result, you need the object of interest as the first argument.

```
> attr(x, "levels")
# [1] "no"  "yes"
```

You can also view all the attributes associated with an object with `attributes`

```
> attributes(x)
# $levels
# [1] "no"  "yes"
#
# $class
# [1] "factor"
```

and the levels of a factor with `levels`

```
> levels(x)
# [1] "no"  "yes"
```

Answer (score 0):

When an object with an attribute is printed, the default (which happens unless there is a special print method for the object's class) is to show attribute value in the style described in the question. For example:

```
structure(1:5, an_attribute = "something")
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5
## attr(,"an_attribute")
## [1] "something"
```

This is purely printed information though; as noted by Richard Scriven, you can't call the `attr` function with the first argument missing.